# NetBeans 6.8 Collaborative editing

Tags: netbeans, collaboration

I remember using collaborative text editing in NetBeans some versions ago. You could edit a file from your project collaboratively with a partner, hosting a server on your computer. It was something similar to Gobby (Kobby). I think you even had a chat client.

I'm using NetBeans 6.8 now after a long time with Eclipse. I see there's integration with Kenai, but this makes no sense unless you're working on a free software project and hosting it over there.

I found this: http://collabed.org/ but it just opens a new window with shared text or something, not exactly what I'm looking for.

Any ideas if there's a way to get this functionality on NetBeans 6.8?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the Developer collaboration module was discontinued after the release of NetBeans 6.5.... at least as a stand-alone feature.

I was able to load it into NetBeans 6.8, by registering the NB 6.5 update center.

I am not sure that it will work, since I do not have a collab server to use, or an extended team to collab with.

The url for the NetBeans 6.5 update center is: http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/6.5/uc/final/stable/catalog.xml.gz.

The name of the module is "Developer Collaboration".

Comment: Thanks, that sucks. I hope they bring that feature back on future versions.